Option to automatically save edited files before a test execution
I have not used Delphi for a long time, now getting back with Delphi 12 CE.
I think I remember an option to automatically save all changes before executing (with F9).
I don't find such an option. Does anyone know where it might be?
I searched all of the options, but t must be somewhere.

Years ago IDE Insight was added to allow searching the IDE for settings. It is the small text box in the upper right. Seaching for save brings up a bunch of settings one of which describes what you want. Becoming familar with IDE Insight is worthwhile.


Tools > Options > IDE > Saving and Recovering > Autosave > Save files when compiling or running
